# Ordering Firebase posts Chronologically Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have added posts to firebase and I am wondering how I can pull the posts chronologically based on when the user has posted them.

My Database is set up like below [image]

The first node after comments is the User ID and then the posts are underneath that. Obviously, these posts are in order, however if a new user posts something in between "posting" and "another 1" ,for example, how would I pull that so it shows up in between.

Is there a way to remove the autoID and just use the userID as a key? The problem I am running into is the previous post is overwritten then.

I am accepting the answer as it is the most thorough. What I did to solve my problem was just create the unique key as the first node and then use the UID as a child and the comment as a child. Then I pull the unique key's as they are in order and find the comment associated with the uid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answers all have merit but a more complete solution includes timestamping the post and [denormalizing your data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) so it can be queried (assuming it would be queried at some point). In Firebase, flatter is better.

```
posts
   post_0
     title: "Posts And Posting"
     msg: "I think there should be more posts about posting"
     by_uid: "uid_0"
     timestamp: "20171030105500"
     inv_timestamp: "-20171030105500"
     uid_time: "uid_0_ 20171030105500"
     uid_inv_time: "uid_0_-20171030105500"

comments:
   comment_0
     for_post: "post_0"
     text: "Yeah, posts about posting are informative"
     by_uid: "uid_1"
     timestamp: "20171030105700"
     inv_timestamp: "-20171030105700"
     uid_time: "uid_1_20171030105700"
     uid_inv_time: "uid_1_-20171030105700"
   comment_1
     for_post: "post_0"
     text: "Noooo mooooore posts, please"
     by_uid: "uid_2"
     timestamp: "20171030110300"
     inv_timestamp: "-20171030110300"
     uid_time: "uid_2_20171030110300"
     uid_inv_time: "uid_2_-20171030110300"
```

With this structure we can

```
get posts and their comments and order them ascending or descending
query for all posts within the last week
all comments or posts made by a user
all comments or posts made by a user within a date range (tricky, huh)
```

I threw a couple of other key: value pairs in there to round it out a bit: compound values, query-ing ascending and descending, timestamp.

Comment: This can cause issues when you get to comment_10, strings are ordered lexicographically. so the order would be comment_1, comment_10, comment_2 etc, you can prefix with 0 but that just pushes the problem further away :(. `orderByKey()` does give the unique keys in the correct order if that helps?

Comment: @av4625 Normally, you would not use static comment keys like that (c_0, c_1 etc). I was using those as placeholders for keys generated with .childByAutoId (-Jook9i900s, -J7h89090ks0k0 etc).

Comment: fair enough, just wanted to make sure everyone is clear as you wont see the issue until number 10 then its harder to redesign

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the userID as key value instead of the autoID, because the key must be unique, thats why Firebase just updates the value and does not add another one with the same key. Normally Firebase nodes are ordered chronologically by default, so if you pull the values, those should be in the right order. However if you wanna make sure about that, you can add a timestamp value and set a server timestamp. After pulling the data you can order it by that timestamp (I think there is actually a timestamp saved automatically by firebase that you can access somehow, but you need to look that up in the documentation). If I got it right, in order to accomplish what you want, you need to change the structure of your database. For example you could maybe use the autoID but save the userID you wanted to use as key as a value if you need that. Hope I got your idea right, if not just be more precise and I will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase keys *are* chronological by default - it's built into their key generation algorithm. I think you need to restructure/rethink your data.

Your **POSTS** database should (possibly) have the comments listed with each post, and then you can duplicate on the user record if needed for faster retrieval if they need to be accessed by user. So something like:

```
POSTS
  - post (unique key)
    - title (text)
    - date (timestamp)
    - comments
      - comment (unique key)
        - text (text)
        - user_id (user key)
        - date (timestamp)
```

When you pull the comments, you shouldn't be pulling them from a bunch of different users. That could result it a lot of queries and a *ton* of load time. Instead, the comments could be added (chronologically of course) to the post object itself, and also to the user if you want to keep a reference there. Unlike in MySQL, NoSQL databases can have quite a bit of this data duplication.