# Handling a dating app's preferences (filters) on a list of Users fetched from Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase

I am building a dating feature on my app and thus have a `ViewController` which fetches all `Users` (including attributes eg; `birthday`, `gender`, `status`, etc..) from `Firebase` located within a radius of a `Venue`.

The snapshot is saved in a `Users` array used to populate a `CollectionView`.

I am trying to figure out the best approach to implementing a feature to **filter** **results** eg; display male only, female, age range, status etc...

What is the best approach to dealing with preferences filtering on a Firebase list:

- Apply the filter to the local `User` array and reload data? or
- Create a new `Firebase` query based on the user's preferences, execute query and overwrite the `User` array to reload the data?

Comment: While the question is clear the parameters are not so it would be hard to answer. Firebase does not offer a 'built-in' way to query across multiple fields. It can be done via compound values, there are some drawbacks. If the app has 100-1000 users, best bet is to load it all in and filter in code. If each /users node is fairly small you may be able to load more. Reducing the amount fo data needed can be key; For example the user starts with Male or Female; then do a split half search to reduce the amount of data needed as now you load just males and females and query those in code.

Comment: There are a LOT of questions about querying on multiple fields in Firebase here on SO so I would suggest doing some research to see what the options are. Also look into compound values like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531960/count-unseen-messages-with-firebase-in-swift/49539137#49539137) and [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005529/ordering-firebase-posts-chronologically-swift/47021634#47021634) and [compound values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769285/query-over-list-in-firebase/50770576#50770576)