# User feed with posts of people they follow using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to implement a feed for my users where they can only see posts from people they follow. My database looks like this:

```
users
-- userID_1
---- userName: "PennyWise"
---- userGender: "M"
---- userFollowing
------ userID_2: true
------ userID_3: true
------ userID_4: true
---- userFollowers
------ userID_2: true
------ userID_4: true

posts
-- postID_1
---- userID: userID_1
---- postContent: "some content"
---- postTimeStamp: 1540026290
-- postID_2
---- userID: userID_2
---- postContent: "another post"
---- postTimeStamp: 1540027077
```

I would now like to add the following structure to my database:

```
feed
-- userID_1
---- postID_1
------ postTimeStamp: 1540026290
---- postID_2
------ postTimeStamp: 1540027077
```

I am adding the timestamp to make sorting easier when retrieving data. I am pretty sure I can figure out how to display the right items, by retrieving the postIDs under the logged in userID and then run a foreach loop to retrieve the additional information based on the postID.

My biggest concern about this implementation and referencing to the data is when I am adding a new post. Imagine I have 1,200 followers and I would have to add the postID to each of those followers' feed. I have read about the possibility of performing in batches (500 records each), but I am not entirely sure this would be the best approach? Would I have to run this in the background, if I were to implement it, so the UI doesn't freeze? What happens if connection is lost during the writing process to the database?

I have thought about this a lot over the last days. This question isn't so much about the structure or whatever, as there are lots of post about this already. I was merely wondering if I would be able to implement [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions) as an addition to my realtime database. Would I be able to, using onCreate(), to create the references to the data on the server and push it towards each followers' feed? Or is this simply not possible considering the variables and such? My writing action looks like this, when adding a new post:

```
let newRef = Ref.child("posts").childByAutoId()
newRef.setValue(["userID": loggedInUserID, "postContent": post["postContent"], "postTimeStamp": dateNow)
```

If I was to update all the followers' feed on the client side, I would have to run an additional setValue() for all the followers based on the loggedInUserID. This could probably return some issues when the followers count is high (e.g. 1,200 as I mentioned earlier). What I would like to know is, can Cloud Functions help me with this or should I go with the classic approach?

If not, is referencing a great solution or should I fan out the data and duplicate the entire post - not only the key - to all the followers? I can only imagine the amount of data this would take when creating or editing a new post.

Thank you!

Comment: As you mentioned, there are a lot of identical posts to this and about 100 different solutions. However, I think you may want to consider a different approach. Have users track the feeds they are watching by keeping a reference to the feed id's they are interested in within their own node. Then when they log in, simply add observers to the feeds in their 'watching' list. That puts a bulk of the heavy lifting on Firebase. So *I would have to add the postID to each of those followers' feed* would go away as users would be automatically notified of new posts within the feeds they are watching.

Comment: I don’t see how referencing to the feed within their own node would be a big improvement from creating feed/userID/postID? It’s more or less the same, isn’t it? Except I don’t need access to the other user’s node with personal information. Would it be possible to add the post ID keys to the necessary feeds with Cloud Functions?

Comment: The idea was to eliminate the need to write (unnecessary) data; e.g. *Imagine I have 1,200 followers and I would have to add the postID to each of those followers' feed*. It would also eliminate the need to leverage additional cloud functions, it would keep the code smaller and cleaner and easier to maintain. Users simply subscribe (observe) a feed they want and can also remove it; all with minimal code as Firebase is handling sending out data when it's available instead of having separate code to do that task. Perhaps I don't fully understand the question?

Comment: The idea behind a feed is that it contains all the posts of the users someone is following. I don’t think it would be possible to subscribe to a certain feed as I want users to be able to follow each other. E.g. i want to be able to follow user1, user3 and user4 and then a week later I can unfollow user3. Subscribing to a feed would not be possible then, no?

Comment: I don't see why not. In your current structure if user 1 wants to watch users 2 and user 3 posts, then userID_1 adds a query to the posts node for *userID: userID_2*  and userID: userID_3. Then user 1 will receive all posts from userID_2 and userID_3. That's about it really - no need to store anything else other than which users user 1 wants to observe; *userID_1/userFollowing/userID_2* and *userID_1/userFollowing/userID_3*. You've got that in your structure already so you should be in good shape.

Comment: So basically you suggest to append the userIDs of the followers to the posts? posts/postID/followers/userID?

Comment: No.Obviously I don't fully understand your question but it seems you have everything you need already in place. It's not clear what the purpose is of the feed node is but as it is without that, if each user just adds a query observer to the posts node (per my above comment) for the users they are interested in, they will receive posts from those users.

Comment: I see what you mean, I think. You would query only the posts which contain userIDs which the current logged in user is following? 2 observations: I am already querying on reverseTimeStamp, but could probably resolve this by indexing in Firebase. Second, how could I run a query that checks if the creator of the post’s userID is inside an array (following)?

Comment: Yes. and secondly just read in your userFollowing node and iterate over the uid's, Add an observer for each one.

Comment: Seems like a possibility I guess, but how would I sort them based on timestamp? I limit the results to 20 posts per load, so I have an infinite scrolling mechanism obtaining 20 posts per scroll. That would be nearly impossible implementing the iteration over each userID?

Comment: That could easily be done with a [compound value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531960/count-unseen-messages-with-firebase-in-swift/49539137#49539137) and another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47005529/ordering-firebase-posts-chronologically-swift/47021634#47021634)